# Problemas ao gerar página em PHP a partir de link de menu dinâmico

Tags: php, html

Possuo um menu dinâmico em que ele é gerado a partir das tabelas de meu banco de dados.

```
<?php
    $results = DB::query('select * from categoria');

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<a href="#" class="categoria">'.$row['Nome'].'</a>';
    }  
?>
```

Quero fazer um código em PHP que gere uma página padrão para cada categoria, em que nessa página apareça todos os produtos dessa categoria clicada.

Quando coloco `<a href="paginadeprocessamento.php" class="categoria">` eu não consigo pegar a categoria que o usuário clicou no menu.

Já tentei usar o `name=""` mas acho que só funciona para formulário.

Resumindo: Quero gerar uma página com todos os produtos da categoria em que o usuário clicou no menu dinâmico, porém não sei identificar depois no php em qual ele cliclou.

Dei uma lida rápida sobre htacess e acho que ele pode me ajudar, mas acho que possa ter uma outra solução para isso.

Comment: como é esse menu? menu de links? <a href="#" class="categoria">'.$row['Nome'].</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você pegar alguma informação via URL tens que passar com um parâmetro.

```
 foreach ($results as $row) {    
 echo "<a href="paginadeprocessamento.php?categoria=".$row['Nome']." class="categoria">'.$row['Nome'].'</a>';
```

E no PHP você faz `$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];`

```
select * from ???? where ???? = $categoria
```

> O método GET é utilizado quando queremos passar poucas/pequenas informações para realizar uma pesquisa ou simplesmente passar uma informação para outra página através da URL.
>
> Este método é bem restrito quanto ao tamanho e quantidade das informações que são passadas pela URL.
>
> Como você já percebeu, as informações enviadas ficam visíveis ao visitante, então, quando queremos passar parâmetros confidenciais, como exemplo as senhas, não devemos utilizar esse método. Para isso temos o POST.

Comment: Tinha encontrado outro método mas o seu foi melhor. Muito Obrigado.